# IPv6 address by hostname

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, ipv6

Is there any command in Linux to get the IPv6 address of a hostname?

I tried `NSLookup`, but it doesn't seem to have an option to get the IPv6 address for the specified hostname or perhaps I missed it.

I have a C program that deals with IPv6 and I want to check if I am getting correct results by using a different method to obtain the IPv6 address of a host.

Comment: show us your code and we'll tell you if it's written correctly.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

With `nslookup`, just query for the `AAAA` record type used for IPv6 addresses:

```
nslookup -query=AAAA $hostname
```

Comment: oops, my bad, thanks anyway

Comment: Works at least on Windows XP too.

Answer (score 28):

You can also use [dig](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/dig/) or [host](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/host/):

```
host -t AAAA www.google.com

dig www.google.com AAAA
```